Is there any httpClient request to cancel order on API?
I want to Cancel (not delete) order on Shopify as API in my application.
Currently I am using this piece of code to cancel order
public IActionResult Cancel(double? id)
{
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("");
    APISecurity.InitHeader(_httpClient);
    var response = _httpClient.PostAsync($"orders /{id}/cancel.json/").Result;  //Not compiling, Giving Error (says to include httpContent), I want to send cancel order request

Using postman by API is working fine (using Post Verb). This is URL
https://{apikey}:{apitoken}@storename/admin/api/version/orders/{id}/cancel.json

Looks like you're missing a JSON body with the parameters see the docs https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-07/resources/order#post-orders-order-id-cancel also use await never .Result. Really instead of coding this manually you should get the Swagger/OpenAPI file and generate client classes using NSwag or similar.

If you want CancelAsync then create an ExtensionMethod on HttpClient.

IIRC the HTTP protocol doesn't define a CANCEL verb. If you can make things work using Postman, please edit the question to demonstrate what a successful HTTP session looks like (please, no screenshots; HTTP is text-based, and text we can copy, paste, search, and edit).

@MarkSeemann Why is everyone mentioning a CANCEL verb, the docs specifically say it's a normal POST

@Charlieface Because the code comment in the OP asks for a CancelAsync method, and (apart from the underlying SendAsync implementation workhorse) the HttpClient API only affords request methods modelled after the four HTTP verbs.

@MarkSeemann I think what the OP meant is canceling the order rather than canceling the http request, so the question seems unrelated to programming, it's about Shopify API usage.

Not sure why you want CancelAsync, there is no such HTTP verb. The docs state that it's a normal POST. But you are missing a JSON body for the Post request.
And you set the BaseAddress to "" for some reason, and I'm not sure why you are even setting it here. It should be set once when you create the HttpClient.
Also use await instead of .Result, and the response needs a using.
public async Task<IActionResult> Cancel(
    double id, decimal? amount = null, string? currency = null, bool? email = null, CancellationReason? reason = null)
{
    APISecurity.InitHeader(_httpClient);
    using var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
        $"orders/{id}/cancel.json/",
        new {
            amount = amount.ToString("0.00"),
            currency,
            email,
            reason = reason.ToString(),
        });
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return Ok();
}

To be honest, you'd be far better off just getting the Swagger/OpenAPI definition and creating client classes using NSwag or a similar tool.
